# Count based on other column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel file which is having sorted data( Based on Object column) as below.
[image: Sample excel data]

My requirement is to count object completion status based on the cell value in the column “Fixed/Not”.

For eg: if “Obj1” has the value as “Yes” in all rows, then only I need to consider as completed ,if any one row has value “No” I should not consider that object as completed.

Being new to Excel, I couldn’t find solution for that.
Can anyone please suggest me how I can achieve this.

Thanks
Vijaya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you break it down into something like this, its make it lot easier to accommodate any additions to object list tomorrow. I have used `sumproduct` but you can very well use `countif` if you so desire

[image]

[image]

Formulae

Total To be Completed  `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=$E2)*($A$2:$A$7>0))`

Total Completed `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=$E2)*($C$2:$C$7="Yes")*($A$2:$A$7>0))`

Final Count `=IF(AND(F2<>0,F2=G2),1,0)`

Comment: Its good idea!! can you please paste formula for "Total to be completed" and Total completed here as am not able to see full formula.